# Comparision is not working in Javascript with Strict Equal

Tags: javascript

I have below Basic Javascript to reverse the number which work when I use

> `while (!no == 0)`

But Doesn't work when I use

> `while (!no === 0)`

I have tried in the console for `parseInt(0)` which returns `number` only and my `no` is already `number` so

> why `===` is not working ,Can someone help and explain me better?

```js
function findRepeated(number) {
  var a, no, b, temp = 0;

  no = parseInt(number);


  while (!no == 0) {
    a = no % 10;
    no = parseInt(no / 10);
    temp = temp * 10 + a;
  }
  return temp;
}

console.log(findRepeated(123));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`!no == 0` is not the same as `!(no == 0)`. It is `(!n) == 0`.

Similar, `!no === 0` is `(!no) === 0`.
This always evaluates to `false` because `!no` is a [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Boolean) and `0` is a number.
Values of different types are never `===`.

Read about the [logical NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), the [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) and [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it! Nicely explained though!

Answer (score 4):

### Types

`!no` returns a boolean, it returns false, although the value of no is a number, adding the negate operator in front of any number will return a false, i.e. `console.log(!123 === false)`. As you're probably aware, using `==` will convert the data type for you, where as using `===` will not.

### Example

I like the example of null and undefined.
While `null == undefined` is true, `null === undefined` is false, because the value null is a type of object, whereas the type of undefined is of course undefined.

```js
console.log("test1: " + !123); // false
console.log("test2: " + (!123 === false)); // true
console.log("test3: " + (!123 == 0)); // true
console.log("test4: " + (!123 === 0)); // false

console.log("test5: " + (0 == false)); // true
console.log("test6: " + (0 === false)); // false
console.log("test7: " + (null == undefined)); // true
console.log("test8: " + (null === undefined)); // false

console.log("test9: " + typeof null); // object
console.log("test10: " + typeof undefined); // undefined
```